# New Roof Installed Last Week - Are A Few “Lumps” Normal?

Tags: roof, roofing, shingles

Our roof was installed last week.  Seeing a few “lumps” for lack of a better term.  Close to front gutter.  Is this normal?  It’s December here in Southern California, and some rain is going to hit next week.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shingles should lay flat on the roof deck(usually 4x8 sheets), which should be flat also.  What type of shingles/roofing material is that?  There seems to be quite a few that are not laying flat, that wind could get under and lift.  Might just be shadows/the way the light is hitting.

Comment: Tab asphalt shingles usually have some dabs of tar on the front edge, to help them to stick down so the wind doesn't catch and pull them up. It looks like the shingle areas in question have been trimmed to accommodate a surface that is not square; perhaps the normal tar buttons were trimmed off. A good roofer would apply his/her own dabs of tar in such a case, or take other measures to ensure the shingles lay flat. A few hot days might soften them enough for them to lay down, but you need to make it through this winter. I would call the roofer back.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it. Thanks for the reply. I’ll do that

Comment: @crip659 they’re Owens Corning “duration cool plus” asphalt shingles.  Some of the stuff I read online says it takes a bit for asphalt shingles to “settle”

Answer (score 1):

I would not draw too much concern over the waves you see on the new roof, with the exception of the one in the first picture. I am not familiar with the wintertime temps of southern California, but I would assume it may take a while for the roof to "settle in" with warmer temps in the coming months.

The few waves in the second picture, from what I can tell being a few thousand miles away, it looks like the shingles are still sloping downward, which will not allow the rain to trail back under the sheathing to the roof sheathing/underlayment. The strength of this type of shingle is very resistant to wind, but if you have a high wind condition, and the shingles have not sealed themselves in place yet, there may be a chance that some could be dislodged. Any good roofer will stand by their work, should this happen. By the nature of the their work, I think they are required to warranty their work for 5-10 years??

Back at the first pic. The shingle there looks like it may be high enough to allow the rain to travel under the shingle and get back to the sheathing. As in, what is supposed to be the lowest edge of the shingle is higher than the rest of the same shingle. Rain going under will not be a lot, you may not even know it's happening, as in no leaks visible, but it is still not supposed to happen. This is the one I would call the roofer on, to see why it is up like this. The picture even shows something under that area, could be something, could be nothing, that is up to the roofer to determine and get the high shingle back down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The shingles are still sloping downward.  That first photo is the one that concerns me.  The highs last week were in the 70s and the lows around 50.

Comment: I am thinking that is not enough warmth to get them to lay flat yet. At the same token, with it being cooler, the shingles will be stiff as a board and will resist being blown back by the wind, so I would think. That's good news that they all have a downward slope, that is important. Still, get the roofer to look at the one in the first pic, it looks like it may be held up by something.